# Glide has shown black image when loading by uri

Tags: android, uri, android-glide

When I want to load uri for image by using Glide, my image has shown black image.

Uri:

> content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/4

```
 GlideApp.with(context).load(uri)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .transition(withCrossFade())
                    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                    .into(photoView);
```

I have convert to uri to path and this is not working. I think Glide can't convert from Whatsapp uri to path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to query your images with **EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI** something like this,

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + " =?", new String[]{album}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED);
```

So, You will get file url, instead of content uri like this,

```
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20200127-WA0019.jpg
```

Then you can try this file url to load with Glide like this.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
GlideApp.with(context).load(uri)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .transition(withCrossFade())
        .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
        .into(photoView);
```